# True union join in kdb

Tags: union, kdb

The uj in kdb adds up everything and doesn't matter if it appears previously or not. I would like to know how I can do true union join. Please see my code below:

The keys are `id,currency1,currency2`:

```
tab1:([]Id:1 1;currency1:`USD`USD;currency2:`GBP`EUR;nop:10 10);


  Id currency1 currency2 nop
  -------------------------------------------
   1  USD       GBP       10 
   1  USD       EUR       10

tab2:([]Id:1 1;trade:2222 5555;currency1:`USD`USD;currency2:`GBP`JPY)


 Id trade currency1 currency2
 -----------------------------------------------
 1  2222    USD       GBP      
 1  5555    USD       JPY
```

I want to make it look like

```
        Id currency1 currency2 nop     trade
       ----------------------------------------
        1   USD       GBP       10     2222
        1   USD       EUR       10
         1  USD       JPY               5555
```

I was thinking to use uj and first argument to use left join and the second one to select the one in tab2 but not in tab 1 and join. But what I need to do is to join id,currency1 and currency2 together to form another column.  I am thinking it is not that efficient.

### Update

How can I do in this case

```
tab1:([]Id:1 1 1 1;currency1:`USD`USD`USD`USD;currency2:`GBP`GBP`GBP`EUR;tradeId:10 20 30 40);

tab2:([]Id:1 1;trade:2222 5555;currency1:`USD`USD;currency2:`GBP`JPY)
```

If there are duplicated of id 1 currency 1 and currency2, how should I do it?
I want it to be looked like:

```
Id currency1 currency2| tradeId trade
----------------------| -------------
1  USD       GBP      | 10      2222 
1  USD       GBP      | 20      2222
1  USD       GBP      | 30      2222
1  USD       EUR      | 40           
1  USD       JPY      |         5555
```

My answer is this:

```
uj[tab1 lj 3!tab2;select from (tab2 lj 3!tab1) where null tradeId]
```

I wonder if there is a faster way, and wonder if it is ok to say null tradeId?

Answer (score 2):

```
q)t1:([]Id:1 1;currency1:`USD`USD;currency2:`GBP`EUR;nop:10 10);
q)t2:([]Id:1 1; currency1:`USD`USD;currency2:`GBP`JPY; trade:2222 5555);

q)t1
Id currency1 currency2 nop
--------------------------
1  USD       GBP       10
1  USD       EUR       10

q)t2
Id currency1 currency2 trade
----------------------------
1  USD       GBP       2222
1  USD       JPY       5555

q)0!(3!t1) uj 3!t2
Id currency1 currency2 nop trade
--------------------------------
1  USD       GBP       10  2222
1  USD       EUR       10
1  USD       JPY           5555
```

uj behaves differently with keyed tables:
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/qsql-inner-left-joins#union-join
"update existing records in kt1 with matches from kt2, append any non-matches."

Comment: omg you are my hero. i wish i can click on the arrow for your answer

Comment: If you believe a question is answered you can mark the solution that helped most. This rewards the person that posted the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: hey Ryan, do you mind looking at my updated question and help me out again? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an answer for your updated question.

```
q){(y lj x xkey z)uj 0!(x#y)_x xkey z}[`Id`currency1`currency2;tab1;tab2]
Id currency1 currency2 tradeId trade
------------------------------------
1  USD       GBP       10      2222
1  USD       GBP       20      2222
1  USD       GBP       30      2222
1  USD       EUR       40
1  USD       JPY               5555
q)
```

Note that your requested output isn’t a valid keyed table, since it contains duplicate keys; this is as close as you can get.